# Eclipse plugin - what is the benefit of using Adapter instead of a cast?

Tags: java, eclipse, casting, eclipse-plugin, adapter

If you get a selection of projects as IStructuredSelection, use .toArray() to get their Object[]-content, then why does casting each Object to IAdaptable and then simply casting again to IJavaProject work fine for me and I get all the Classes/Interfaces with their methods....

But when using (IJavaProject) adaptable.getAdapter(IJavaProject.class) instead, some interface methods get lost?

What exactly does the Adapter do (other than "Returns an object which is an instance of the given class parameter...") and why does everyone recommend to use it instead of a cast? Here is the relevant code

```
    IAdaptable adaptable = (IAdaptable) selectedObject;
    IJavaProject javaProject = (IJavaProject) adaptable.getAdapter(IJavaProject.class);
    final IProject iProject = javaProject.getProject();
    iProject.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor());
    final IJavaProject javaRefreshedProject = JavaCore.create(iProject);
    //processing further using ASTParser and CompilationUnit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many objects you get from a selection do not implement things like `IProject` or `IJavaProject` instead they are some internal class that is more suited to the way the code wants to present a view or editor.

In this case you cannot use a cast because the selection object does not implement the interface you want.

The user interface objects may implement `IAdaptable` which allows you to retrieve the underlying class using `object.getAdapter(...)`.

However not all objects implement `IAdaptable` themselves, instead they use the `registerAdapters` method of the `IAdapterManager` to declare a completely different class that converts from the UI object to the underlying object. In this case you use

```
IProject project = (IProject)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(object, IProject.class);
```

You can use a utility method like the following to deal with all possibilities:

```
public static <AdapterType> AdapterType adapt(Object adaptableObject, Class<AdapterType> adapterType)
{
  if (adaptableObject == null)
    return null;

  // Is the object the desired type?

  if (adapterType.isInstance(adaptableObject))
    return adapterType.cast(adaptableObject);

  // Does object adapt to the type?

  if (adaptableObject instanceof IAdaptable)
   {
     AdapterType result = adapterType.cast(((IAdaptable)adaptableObject).getAdapter(adapterType));
     if (result != null)
       return result;
   }

  // Try the platform adapter manager

  return adapterType.cast(Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(adaptableObject, adapterType));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately I did try Platform-Adapter already. I also tried to get the IProjects from the workspace(root) directly, without any UI-selection. But for some reason a simple cast on the contents of a UI selection works best... I will try to find out where the information gets lost; but analyzing such deep variables while debugging takes so much time

Comment: If you have a `IWorkspaceRoot` you call `IWorkspaceRoot.getProjects()` but that is nothing to do with adapters. `IWorkspaceRoot` does not know anything about `IJavaProject` which is a JDT only concept.

Comment: But you can positively check for isNatureEnabled of an iproject and use JavaCore.create(project) to make it an JDT-IJavaProject if it is; but as I said, this method doesn't work either for me for some reason... I think the CompilationUnit-visitor is at fault here though, not the adapters...

Comment: Yes I believe that should work, I see 269 uses of this in Eclipse + JDT. This does not have much to do with adapters.

Comment: You were right; I found the error; duplicate scanned instances were created at some point. The Adapter was working correctly. Now I don't have to spend another 3 hours looking in the wrong place; thanks again